# Is there a way to choose the path of named volumes with the default volume drives in docker?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

Is there a way to choose the path of named volumes with the default volume drives in docker?

I know I can bind mount volumes in each service. I know I can create named volumes outside of services and them share them by mounting them in each service. But I can't find out a way to get the data (to be shared) on a path that I select instead of docker's /var/lib/docker/volumes/.

Anyone tried to share a volume as a mount point in two different containers of the same docker-compose file where the volume is a location at your choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with the built-in docker volume plugin. You need to install a thirdparty plugin like below

https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CWSpear/local-persist/master/scripts/install.sh | sudo bash

docker volume create -d local-persist -o mountpoint=/data/images --name=images

docker run -d -v images:/path/to/images/on/one/ one
docker run -d -v images:/path/to/images/on/two/ two
```

Comment: I feared that the only way was going with the installation of a third party plugin. Thank you though!